# var.test and t.test in r

Tags: r

I am a newbie in R and currently I'm crash into this problem when trying to do a t-test.

I am working on the data set Cars93 in MASS, filter out type t1 (Compact) and type t2 (Large) from Type in Cars93 to get 2 separate dataframe called df.t1 and df.t2

Now I want to compare the means of MPG.City of type t1 and type t1

What I have done are

```
var.test(df.t1$MPG.city ~ df.t2$MPG.city)
t.test(Cars93$MPG.city[Cars93$Type ==`type t1`]~ Cars93$MPG.city[Cars93$Type ==`type t2`])
```

However R shows:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = df.t1$MPG.city ~ df.t2$MPG.city): 
variable lengths differ (found for 'df.t2$MPG.city')
```

Please if anyone could help me look into this. I would be truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to subset the data in the way you have described (creating two separate data.frames, which result in different lengths and throw an error) - try this:

```
data("Cars93", package = "MASS")

df <- Cars93[Cars93$Type %in% c("Compact", "Large"), ]

var.test(df$MPG.city ~ df$Type)
t.test(df$MPG.city ~ df$Type)
```

Comment: thank you a lot for such a prompt answer however, I have to compare the means of MPG.City of Compact and Large in the same df data set, so how would I fix the problem now

Comment: Thats what this does - see output from `t.test`

Comment: ohhhh it turned out amazingg, one more quick question: i tried adressing df <- Cars93[Cars93$Type %in% c("type t1", "type t2"), ] as I have already assigned them Compact and Large previously, however it show: Error in var.test.formula(df2$MPG.city ~ df2$Type) : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels. Could you please clarify how is that an error. Thank you alot

Comment: ohh waitt, i have figured it out. Thank you so much. You're a life-saver. Have a great weekend ^^